# ruby gem to auto reload config files during runtime

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am looking for a ruby gem ( or a idea to develop one) which can refresh config files(yaml) during runtime. So that I can store in variable and use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using for example [Watchr](https://github.com/mynyml/watchr) or [Guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) you can monitor files and act on changes to them.

The actual action to take when a file changes depends entirely on your specific setup and situation, so you're on your own there. Or you need to provide more information.

Answer (score 4):

There's a config object in [Configurabilty](http://rubygems.org/gems/configurability) (disclosure: I'm the author) which you can use either on its own, or as part of the Configurability mixin. From [the documentation](http://deveiate.org/code/configurability/):

Configurability also includes `Configurability::Config`, a fairly simple
configuration object class that can be used to load a YAML configuration file,
and then present both a Hash-like and a Struct-like interface for reading
configuration sections and values; it's meant to be used in tandem with Configurability, but it's also useful on its own.

Here's a quick example to demonstrate some of its features. Suppose you have a
config file that looks like this:

```
--- 
database: 
  development: 
    adapter: sqlite3
    database: db/dev.db
    pool: 5
    timeout: 5000
  testing: 
    adapter: sqlite3
    database: db/testing.db
    pool: 2
    timeout: 5000
  production: 
    adapter: postgres
    database: fixedassets
    pool: 25
    timeout: 50
ldap: 
  uri: ldap://ldap.acme.com/dc=acme,dc=com
  bind_dn: cn=web,dc=acme,dc=com
  bind_pass: Mut@ge.Mix@ge
branding: 
  header: "#333"
  title: "#dedede"
  anchor: "#9fc8d4"
```

You can load this config like so:

```
require 'configurability/config'
config = Configurability::Config.load( 'examples/config.yml' )
# => #<Configurability::Config:0x1018a7c7016 loaded from 
    examples/config.yml; 3 sections: database, ldap, branding>
```

And then access it using struct-like methods:

```
config.database
# => #<Configurability::Config::Struct:101806fb816
    {:development=>{:adapter=>"sqlite3", :database=>"db/dev.db", :pool=>5,
    :timeout=>5000}, :testing=>{:adapter=>"sqlite3",
    :database=>"db/testing.db", :pool=>2, :timeout=>5000},
    :production=>{:adapter=>"postgres", :database=>"fixedassets",
    :pool=>25, :timeout=>50}}>

config.database.development.adapter
# => "sqlite3"

config.ldap.uri
# => "ldap://ldap.acme.com/dc=acme,dc=com"

config.branding.title
# => "#dedede"
```

or using a Hash-like interface using either `Symbol`s, `String`s, or a mix of
both:

```
config[:branding][:title]
# => "#dedede"

config['branding']['header']
# => "#333"

config['branding'][:anchor]
# => "#9fc8d4"
```

You can install it via the Configurability interface:

```
config.install
```

Check to see if the file it was loaded from has changed since you
loaded it:

```
config.changed?
# => false

# Simulate changing the file by manually changing its mtime
File.utime( Time.now, Time.now, config.path )
config.changed?
# => true
```

If it has changed (or even if it hasn't), you can reload it, which automatically re-installs it via the Configurability interface:

```
config.reload
```

You can make modifications via the same Struct- or Hash-like interfaces and write the modified config back out to the same file:

```
config.database.testing.adapter = 'mysql'
config[:database]['testing'].database = 't_fixedassets'
```

then dump it to a YAML string:

```
config.dump
# => "--- \ndatabase: \n  development: \n    adapter: sqlite3\n   
    database: db/dev.db\n    pool: 5\n    timeout: 5000\n  testing: \n   
    adapter: mysql\n    database: t_fixedassets\n    pool: 2\n    timeout:
    5000\n  production: \n    adapter: postgres\n    database:
    fixedassets\n    pool: 25\n    timeout: 50\nldap: \n  uri:
    ldap://ldap.acme.com/dc=acme,dc=com\n  bind_dn:
    cn=web,dc=acme,dc=com\n  bind_pass: Mut@ge.Mix@ge\nbranding: \n 
    header: \"#333\"\n  title: \"#dedede\"\n  anchor: \"#9fc8d4\"\n"
```

or write it back to the file it was loaded from:

```
config.write
```

Comment: Thats very helpful when it comes to caching information in configuration files at runtime. I have such cases and this is pretty easy to handle right now. Thank you!